# 条件分岐の値が何なのかわかりません。

Tags: jsp

#### 前提・実現したいこと

クエリストリングから受け取った値をStringの変数に代入し、条件分岐したい。

#### 該当のソースコード

商品1を表示したいのですが、、、

このようなURLを入力。

```
http://localhost:8080/WebApplication1/programing_base1.jsp?param1=1&param2=2&param3=3
```

【programing_base1.jsp】

```
<%
    String product1 = request.getParameter("param1"); 
    String product2 = request.getParameter("param2"); 
    String product3 = request.getParameter("param3");
    
    out.print(product1);
    if (product1 == "1"){←ここが通らないです。
        out.println("商品1");
      out.print(product1);
    }
    if (product2 == "2"){
        out.print("商品2");
    }
%>
```

この結果、ブラウザに表示されるのは1なのです…
商品1のしたのproduct1も表示されませんので、ifの条件を通っていないようです。。。

product1は文字列型ですので、product1 == "1"は通るかと思ったのですが、通りませんでした。

クエリストリングで取得し、product1に代入した値は一体何になっているのでしょうか？

ご教示お願いします。

マルチポスト
[テラテイルでも質問しています。](https://teratail.com/questions/56692?modal=q-comp)

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しました。

==ではなく"1".equals(product1) を条件にすることで解決しました。

文字列型の比較ではequalsを使わないといけないのですね。